# What constitutes "excellent" undergraduate research

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, computer-science

I am a junior right now and I plan on doing research over the summer and senior year. I was wondering what PhD admissions committees defined as good research experience from undergraduates in computer science?

Answer (score 2):

Ok I did my studies and teaching in CS, so the following is my opinion from excellent to normal.

**Excellent**: The excellent case would be achieving a research contribution, and a publication; with a help of a supervisor (and/or his/her PhD students). Also know what you want to do with your PhD (if you decided to do so).

**Good**: The good case would be for you to do a research, learn how to approach reading and writing research to some extend, and now what you want to do for your PhD (if you decided to do so).

**Normal**: The normal case would be the supervisor's students help you to start thinking research. In this case you will get some idea about the research and surrounding activities.

Comment: I am not sure this is true. I does seem a bit much to ask achieving a research contribution from an undergraduate. or am i misunderstanding you here?

Comment: @KenGoldhaus I think Dave is saying that an excellent undergraduate would achieve this (often with some luck and a good supervisor!). Normally, it is not the case.

Comment: I took excellent to mean equivalent to an A in the US / > 70 % in the UK and I do not think that a research *contribution* is required for this. Or is this not meant here maybe?

Comment: @KenGoldhaus The OP hasn't provided much contest, but it's possible he's going off language about being admitted to a PhD program without a Masters. When I was looking at that, several programs referred to "excellent" or "exceptional" research experiences, and for that, I don't think it's unreasonable to assume it meant a publication.